# What happens to Google Analytics when I run the page locally?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Using Google Analytics with my Web Pages / Java Script application I just wonder what happens to the statistics when I run (test) the pages locally? Testing the application is done on a local web server, is this included in the statistcis?

Or, in turn, is this the keyline

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mydomain.org']);
```

and all "recording" is restricted to mydomain.org? Any idea how this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set your `setDomainName` for a domain that doesn't match the current domain, it will not work.

So, if its set to `mydomain.org`, and you're on `testing-domain.org`, Google Analytics will try to set the cookies to `mydomain.org` and fail (because the cookies won't be set, as you can't set external domain cookies from JavaScript); seeing no cookies, it will not make the `__utm.gif` request go Google Analytics, and no data will be tracked.

The same thing will occur if you execute Google Analytics on the `file://` protocol.

(The exception to the `setDomainName` rule is if you pass either a non-domain string like `(none)` or an empty string to `setDomainName`, which has the effect of setting the domain hash (a cookie identifier to prevent data collision) to `1` and setting the Google Analytics cookies to the domain of `document.domain`

Comment: Thanks, it is somehow what I have guessed but I am very glad to have it confirmed and explained in detail. So basically it does what I want.

Can I set more than one domain if I own multiple domains referring to the same content?